# Create visual scratch-like diagrams from code

Tags: diagram, mit-scratch

I'm making a user guide for a program I made and I want to explain what it does step by step. I want to create some kind of code diagram that visually shows my code. I don't need it to be automatically generated or anything. Just looking for something like scratch but without the actual programming part, more like being able to put my own text in any block and connecting it to other blocks, all visually. Like pseudocode but more visual.

Comment: Check https://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Products/CodeRocketDesigner and https://www.yworks.com/products/yed

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [Snap*!*](https://snap.berkeley.edu/) is appropriate here?

With Snap, you can make your own blocks of any category (e.g. motion, control) and any shape (e.g. stack, reporter, C-style like "if"). And you can right-click on a script and click "script pic...", which will download a screenshot of the script on a transparent background, handy for embedding into a paint editor.

Those "script pics" look like this:

[image: "write the text"; "share stack overflow post"; "celebrate (1000)"]